# React react-html-parser how to convert html element to string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, parsing

I use react-html-parser inside a string, I set html elements, but now I need the html element to be displayed as a string and not as a tag. How can I reolise this?

```
{
    titleName: "Creating Your First JavaScript",
    heading: 'Ready. Set. JavaScript!',
    iconName: faDotCircle,
    description: [
        `
        <h2 class="title_description">Let’s start</h2>
        With the basics and add some JavaScript to a webpage. <script> and </script>
        `
    ],
},
```

Please pay attention to `<script> and </script>` I want to display as text I wanted to repeat again I use react-html-parser https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

Comment: You can use ReacDOMServer.renderToString(), https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Comment: Thanks for the help, I got it, but there was one problem. This is my code where I applied renderTostring `${ReactDOMServer.renderToString ("<script> and </script>")}` but I can’t apply styles or change the color of the text because everything is rendered into a string inside renderTostring